# Build Events, permission when run a script

Tags: c#, .net, windows, batch-file

I have a `.bat` script with I configure to run in `my post-build event` `call $(ProjectDir)scripts\install.bat`, this script to install a service in my local machine.

When I open a `cmd` and `run as administrator`, this script works, but if I run in normal `cmd` doesn't work. Exist some way I run `call $(ProjectDir)scripts\install.bat` in administrator mode in visual studio in `post-build event command line` or someone other way to script works in normal command line.

Note: I have administrador privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is Windows 7 or later:

Even though you have administrator privileges on the machine, you still need to run Visual Studio with administrative privileges to do things that a normal user can't do, because of [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control).  Right-click on your VS icon, and select "Run as Administrator".

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a few years too late, but here is the solution for anyone still searching.

Just add this to the top of your batch file and it will ask UAC for admin rights before executing the rest of the script.

if not "%1"=="am_admin" (powershell start -verb runas '%0' am_admin & exit /b)

Comment: This is awesome. How is this answer not upvoted more?